# signing in with google with ad b2c xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I can sign in with local account, Microsoft and facebook - however I get an error when trying to sign in with a google account.  I am using the test project https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices/TodoAzureAuthADB2CClientFlow/

The error is : redirect_uri_mismatch.

Comment: Sounds like the redirect URI specified in the Google app is somehow not matching to the one that B2C specifies at runtime? There could be a problem in your configuration on the Google side.

Comment: Check if the redirect URI should be like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/{tenant}/oauth2/authresp`in the Authorized redirect URIs field in Google Developers Console.

Comment: The problem was a case-sensitive issue (I had the tenant called somethingTenant.onmicrosoft.com - with the T as uppercase). In the google api credentials I needed to change it to lowercase t

Comment: You got that. Actually, When you create a tenant, you can input a uppercase in the tenant name, but the name are also lowercases in the backend acutally. Feel free to post an answer to this issue.:-)

Comment: I had a mobile app which worked with https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp as a authorized url in google. trying to figure out why that happened. or i might have missed something

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be caused by the mismatched redirect URI in the Google API credentials.

According to the OP's comment, the problem was a case-sensitive issue.  Actually, when you create a tenant, you can input an uppercase in the tenant name, but the name is also lowercase in the backend actually. So, we should use all lowercase characters in the redirect URI.